# Custom rake task fails with uninitialized constant Tasks::DatabaseTasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I'm trying to customize `db:structure:dump` and `db:structure:load` tasks, but following error is occured:

```
$ rake db:structure:dump
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Tasks::DatabaseTasks
```

The code that I'm use is just copy from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake with few lines removed:

```
# lib/tasks/db.rake
require 'active_record'

Rake::Task['db:structure:dump'].clear

namespace :db do
  namespace :structure do
    desc 'Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql. Specify another file with DB_STRUCTURE=db/my_structure.sql'
    task :dump => [:environment, :load_config] do
      abcs = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
      filename = ENV['DB_STRUCTURE'] || File.join(Rails.root, "db", "structure.sql")
      case abcs[Rails.env]['adapter']
      when /mysql/, /postgresql/, /sqlite/
        ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.structure_dump(abcs[Rails.env], filename)
      else
        raise "Task not supported by '#{abcs[Rails.env]["adapter"]}'"
      end

      db_namespace['structure:dump'].reenable
    end
  end
end
```

What else I should require or include?

Comment: Why are you requiring active record if you are loading the rails environment?

Comment: It is on the first line of `lib/tasks/db.rake` file: `require 'active_record'`

Comment: Kind of. I needed structure for legacy database. It is not going to change. So I've just got structure file manually and put it into git repository.